# How to retrieve data from database using Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

**Solved**
Somehow, as commented by a user, moving the template from the webpage into the vue script solved the problem. I am not completely sure why though. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/eyvm3s6t/) is a working fiddle that also works on my setup.

**Original Question**
I have some Laravel experience but am quite new to using Vue. I would like
to have a page that displays certain values from a database, when a value is added or deleted, I would like to have the page automatically updated without reloading.
I believe this is exactly what you use Vue for.

I'm running Laravel 5.7.16 and installed vue 2.5.21 and vue-resource 1.5.1 using npm install. The database is running on MariaDB 10.1.35.

So far I'm trying to make an http GET request from vue, the GET url has a web route set up, for this route I will make a function that retrieves the data from the database. However, I can't seem to get the http request to work propperly.

These are my files:

**webpage.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div id="app" class="container">
        <p>@{{ test }}</p>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/vue.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/vue-resource.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

Some sources I have found online use the script tag to load in vue, other use 'require' from within a .js file. For me this is working now but I am not sure if this is the best way.

**script.js**

```
var vue = new Vue({
el: '#app',

data: {
    test: 'old data',
},

mounted: function() {

    var url = "/test";

    this.$http.get(url).then(response => {

        // get body data
        this.test= response.body;
        return this.test;

    });

}
});
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/test', function()
{
    return 'new data';
});
```

The code above seems to always display 'old data' where I would expect it to display 'new data'. I read somewhere in the vue docs that 'ready' is depricated in Vue 2.x and that I sould use 'mounted' instead. However, it doesn't seem like this function is run while loading the page.

Can someone give a clear example of Vue making an http GET request to retrieve some value and having that value displayed on a web page? I will worry about having it auto updated once I can get this working.

Comment: Are you sure the `/test` route is working correctly? Your `this.$http.get` doesn't have an error handler, so check your browser's network tab and see if it's failing for some reason.

Comment: Good idea, however the console.log displays 'new data' so my /test route is working

Comment: Does `this.test = 'foo'` right in your `mounted()` function work?

Comment: Very interesting, it seems that the suggestion by @ceejayoz displays 'foo' on the web page. The http request is probably handles async. and the value is displayed before the http call finishes. Any suggestion on how to implement this?

Comment: I did some testing and it seems that my webpage doesnt update the @{{test}} value when the underlying data.test does get changed in the .js bit, it just takes a little time for the http request to give a response. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Well, your Vue component is targeted at `#app`, but I don't see a `<div id="app">` anywhere. We can't see what's in `layouts.app`, but if you don't have that div anywhere, Vue's not doing anything.

Comment: Ah thanks @ceejayoz, I saw I forgot to add the id to the parent div. I edited my question. However it is still not working and I find it weird that the DOM updates other times when the data was edited when the id was not set

Comment: Check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dccbbkam/2/ It works in browser, but when I literally copy this in my code (using the cdns provided instead of my downloaded vue.min and vue-resource.min) it doesn't work

Comment: @Bobray Could you try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyvm3s6t/)? Note, that template moved to Vue component itself.

Comment: @Styx, wow, this worked. Any idea as to why this behaves different on my setup?

Comment: @Bobray Honestly, have no idea :) It isn't like Laravel renders `{{ test }}` itself (as I initially thought, despite `@` added), since you mentioned that `this.test = 'foo'` worked as expected, so I'm really in the dark here. I'd need to see your complete code set to find the reason of such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

After you make the HTTP request, you need to set the value of `test` to the response. For example:

```
var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        test: 'old data',
    },

    mounted: function() {

        var url = "/test";

        this.$http.get(url).then(response => {
            this.test = response.body; 
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your method but the result is still the same. I suspect that the mounted function might run after the data.test is displayed using vue, since the web page displays 'old data', but my console.log is logging 'new data'

Comment: `this.test` won't work based on your edited answer as it will be tied to the closure's scope. That's why I used self.

Comment: I will edit this into my question, but even with 'self' the test value seems to be displayed before the http request is finished

Comment: Did you see `new data` after the request was done? Also, just want to ask, where did you add the `#app` container? In your master layout?

Comment: @Mozammil My understanding is that `=>` is already supposed to fix the scope issue. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-es6-the-dope-way-part-ii-arrow-functions-and-the-this-keyword-381ac7a32881

Comment: @Mozammil, thanks for the Fiddle. That is the weird thing, I found multiple examples (including some JSFiddles) online that didn't seem to work for me